# Inner join works Too Slower - just show loading label in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, inner-join

I have 3 tables each have almost 70,000 data
when i execute select query in which i add one inner join than it works faster.

Following works faster

```
select A.id from product as A 
inner join product_cat as B on A.id=B.mapped_id
```

OR

```
select A.id from product  as A 
inner join product_sup as C on A.id = C.mapped_id
```

(It works faster for one inner join)

but when i add both inner join in same select query than it works too slower(Does not display data it just show loading label in phpmyadmin)

```
select A.id 
from product as A 
inner join product_cat as B 
    on A.id = B.mapped_id 
inner join product_sup as C 
    on A.id = C.mapped_id
```

my purpose it only to find out how much record is there in database.
also tried with count function though takes too much time.

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks,

Comment: Quick question (I think I know the answer): Your third code-part is wrong, right? You do product_cat as B twice, and doesn't include product_sup anytime!

Comment: When a database query runs slowly, do an EXPLAIN on the query, and look at the indexes on your tables, and which are actually being used.... posting that information here would also help people to answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EXPLAIN to analyze performance of the query and identify any missing indexes.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

Add your actual query, execution plan printed by EXPLAIN and CREATE TABLE statements of all involved tables to your question if you want to get a specific advice.

Comment: Thanks, As i can not use Explain on query which have two joins, so i use Explain individually (for one inner join) and it shows suggestion to index mapped_id of both table B and C
when i click on index link of mapped_id (Either of table B or C) from phpmyadmin
it also just loading for longer time,
after that i stopped the process 
So, is there any other way of indexing ?

Comment: Of course you can use EXPLAIN on a query with multiple joins, just put EXPLAIN before SELECT and run it.

Comment: Don't use phpmyadmin for long running tasks, use command line mysql client, Mysql Workbench or some other GUI tool instead of web tools.
The statement you have to run is CREATE INDEX mapped_id ON product_cat(mapped_id);

Comment: You should add a `LIMIT` in your query in order to execute the `EXPLAIN`. If there are too many results you couldn`t see the *"explanation"*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your query is trying to return more than 1 million of result and that is the reason fo the slowness. Maybe you are doing a *Cartesian product* between tables `B` and `C`.

Let's put an example.

```
Table (A) = (id=1)
Table (B) = (id=1,mapped_id=1),(id=2,mapped_id=1),
            (id=3,mapped_id=1),(id=4,mapped_id=1)
Table (C) = (id=1,mapped_id=1),(id=2,mapped_id=1), (id=3,mapped_id=1)
```

If we do that query with those data it would return 12 rows, all of them with `A.id=1`

To solve the problem you could try to use a `DISTINCT` on the `SELECT` clause or to do a group with the `GROUP BY`clase, but I think the better solution is to redesing the query depending on your goals.

If you want to use the group by your query will be something like this

```
select A.id from product as A 
inner join product_cat as B on A.id = B.mapped_id 
inner join product_sup as C on A.id = C.mapped_id
group by A.id
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for Response,
Actually I printed wrong query in my question sorry for that,
i Actually executing above query which you mentioned,
    select A.id from product as A 
inner join product_cat as B on A.id = B.mapped_id 
inner join product_sup as C on A.id = C.mapped_id

Can you explain how can i use group by
please,

Comment: I updated the answer with the group by. Nevertheless I think you should follow the advice of @Naktibalda for optimizing your query.